# For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ let $x_n:=\min_{1\leq k < n}\lvert\sin n-\sin k\rvert.\ $ Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n $ converge?

Tags: trigonometry, convergence-divergence, diophantine-approximation, equidistribution

> For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ let $x_n:= \displaystyle\min_{1\leq k <
>  n} \lvert\sin n - \sin k\rvert.\ $ Does
> $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n $ converge?

Consider instead, $a_1 = 0,\ a_2=1, a_3 = \frac{1}{2}, a_4 = \frac{1}{4}, a_5=\frac{3}{4}, a_6 = \frac{1}{8},  a_7 = \frac{3}{8},\ldots . $ Then for each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ let $x_n:= \displaystyle\min_{1\leq k < n} \lvert a_n - a_k\rvert.\ $ This is an example of a bounded sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with the property that
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n $ diverges.

The question is: does the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n $ occur if we instead define $(a_n) = (\sin n). $  But it seems unlikely that $\sin$ behaves similar enough to the sequence in the previous paragraph to enable $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n $ to diverge, although I don't know how to prove this, although it could be as simple as applying a trigonometric identity in a specific way.

Comment: No, because if you look at  any 3 consecutive terms you will see that at least one of them is "large". Draw a picture first and then use some simple algebra.

Comment: @Salcio That's false. You may be observed that behavior in the few first terms but that change later.

Comment: @Salcio It may be the case that for every $n$ there is $N>n$ s.t. $x_N:= \displaystyle\min_{1\leq k <
 N} \lvert\sin N - \sin k\rvert$ is "large", but this is not clear or obvious, and maybe even false.

Comment: _may be even false_ - It is false indeed. Natural angles are dense on the circle, so for any $n$ there is $k$ such that $]n-k| \mod 2\pi < \frac{2\pi}{n}$. The question is "how much smaller" it is. The problem feels related to a rational approximation of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum x_n$ diverges.

First, we may assume $(a_n)$ has all distinct terms. For this, the repeating terms of $(a_n)$ contribute zero toward $\sum x_n$.  Let $(a_n)$ be dense in an interval $(a,b)$. We prove that $(x_n)$ constructed by $x_1=0$, $x_n:= \displaystyle\min_{1\leq k < n} \lvert a_n - a_k\rvert$ gives the divergence of $\sum x_n$. Since $a_n=\sin n$ is dense in $(-1,1)$, $\sum x_n$ is divergent.

To see this, assume that $\sum x_n$ converges. Then there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n>N} x_n < (b-a)/2$.

Let $b_1<\cdots <b_N$ be the numbers $a_1,\ldots, a_N$ in an increasing order. For $a_{N+1}$, it is closest to some number $a_1, \ldots, a_N$. Find the smallest index $k\leq N$ such that $a_{N+1}$ is closest to $a_k$. Then color **red** over the interval $[\min(a_{N+1},a_k),\max(a_{N+1},a_k)]$. The red interval has the length $x_{N+1}$. We repeat the procedure. Given $a_1,\ldots, a_{N+j}$, Find the smallest index $m\leq N+j$ such that $a_m$ is closest to $a_{N+j+1}$. Then color red over $[\min(a_{N+j+1},a_m),\max(a_{N+j+1},a_m)]$.

In this procedure, the new red interval is either contained in the already existing red interval or extends the already existing red interval. Repeating the procedure for $j\rightarrow\infty$, the red intervals are formed over $b_1,\ldots, b_N$. That is, we have at most $N$ red intervals, each containing some $b_i$.

The following figure is an illustration after $j\rightarrow \infty$ in this procedure.
[image]

The sum of measures of the red intervals is at most $\sum_{n>N}x_n <(b-a)/2$. Note also that we have at most $N$ disjoint red intervals here (each of those can be any of the forms $(c,d)$, $(c,d]$, $[c,d)$, or $[c,d]$ after $j\rightarrow\infty$ in the process). All members of $\{a_n: n>N\}$ are in the union of these red intervals, and it is dense in $(a,b)$. However, the sum of measures less than $(b-a)/2$ contradicts the density of $(a_n)$.